# What is the difference between equal ($=$) and colons equal($:=$)?

Tags: notation

From the context I guess colons equals add the implication of setting. As in $t:=0$ means lets set $t=0$.

Comment: What context do you mean?

Comment: usually the symbol $:=$ means "defined as", and the symbol $=$ is used for equations or say that two statements are the same thing

Comment: Sometimes the symbol $:=$ is used in pseudocode of algorithms as the assignment operator

Comment: @HenryLee P. 3 in https://shoup.net/ntb/ntb-v2.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $:=$ and $=$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63553/difference-between-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $t:=0$ notation is borrowed from some computer programming languages. It implies we *define* $t$ to be $0$, so it's not an equation to be solved e.g. or part of some axiom, but an "assignment" of values.

Answer (score 3):

The latter is used to define something. For example we have that $2 + 4 = 6$. That is just a normal equality. But if we have something that we want to define then we can use "$:=$". For example we set $A := \lbrace \text{apple},\text{banana} \rbrace$.